# NSPredicate vs NSRegularExpression result differences

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nspredicate, nsregularexpression

I'm facing a strange situation here, and wanted to ask if any other person see my problem right there.

So, I'm trying to use a regex to check if an URL is valid using this pattern:

```
let pattern = "^(http|https):\\/\\/(.+\\.)(whatever|whenever)\\.com(.+\\/)*platform/outsource"
```

The URL to test is:

```
let strTest = "https://int.me2.whatever.com/RandomStuff;WbSess=mhLkhgmHWGGwDMYQ1sqFvgCp0FNGhhkdhTpv0kpYJvQggST3ll55!217115774!NONE?additional=1&popup=/platform/outsource/&action=openext"
```

So, if I use NSRegularExpression to check, it returns 1 match; But if I use NSPredicate, it says it doesn't match...

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = regex.matches(in: strTest, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: strTest.characters.count))
let regexCondition:Bool = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regex.pattern).evaluate(with: strTest)

print("Regex Matches: \(matches.count)")
print("Predicate Condition: \(regexCondition)")
```

And results are:

```
Regex Matches: 1
Predicate Condition: false
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NSPredicate` with `MATCHES` requires a full string match.

Comment: Just use `NSURL`?

Comment: Yeah, this is serious overkill, `NSURL` will handle all of this lol